# What are "server routers" in the World Wide Web?

Tags: www

I understand that any "Client" (or "agent" or "user agent") interacts on the World Wide Web by this pattern:

```
Client ⟶ Routers(1) ⟶ DNS server ⟶ Routers(2) ⟶ Web Server ⟶ SOME_WEB_PAGE_DATA ⟶ Client
```

- By client (or "agent" or "user agent") I mean to a human or to a software (such as a World Wide Web browser)
- By World Wide Web I mean to websites only (not to native applications which uses the internet but not the World Wide Web via browsers).

**What are "server routers" in the World Wide Web (of groups 1 and 2)?**
I would most like to learn where is this software located (is it in the client's environment or in the remote server environment) and how do they generally work?

Comment: Routing is the process of selecting a path for traffic in a network or between or across multiple networks.Routing is the act of finding a path to a destination and moving data across this path from source to destination. The routing process uses network routing tables, protocols, and algorithms to determine the most efficient path for forwarding the IP packet.refer this:https://medium.com/@wilbo/server-side-vs-client-side-routing-71d710e9227f#:~:text=Routing%20is%20the%20mechanism%20by,data%20or%20a%20new%20webpage.

Answer (score 5):

That's a very confusing description of what happens, and is mixes up network traffic and different requests.

When a client makes an HTTP request for a URL with a hostname in it, it must first convert the hostname to an IP address. It does this by using DNS, typically it will check a local cache first, then contact its local DNS server (which could be on a network router, provided by the ISP, or be a third party one such as [1.1.1.1](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/)).

Once it has the IP address, it will send an HTTP request to the HTTP server on it, an a response will be sent back.

All of those messages (the DNS and HTTP requests and responses) have to travel between the computer the client is running on and the appropriate server. The IP packages are passed from client to a sequence of any numbers of routers until reacting the server (and in reverse for the responses).

Typically the first router will be one that provides an internet connection to the building (with the building's LAN/WLAN on one side and the ISP on the other), then it will be passed through the ISP, onto the public Internet, and then onto routers for the server's ISP before eventually reaching the server.

Sometimes you'll get a router that does clever stuff, like splitting traffic between multiple servers for the sake of load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you're driving along and need to change roads, but don't know which road to take, so you ask for directions at the intersection.  This is what a router does, there can be several routers between the client and the final destination, each directing the request where to go.

It's an older article, but you might find [Mr Packet Goes to Washington](https://rtnetworks.com/OSI.htm) a helpful explanation of how networks work.